# Find an affine application given its values on some lines

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have to find explicitly and verify that it is unique an affine application of the real affine plane into itself such that:

i) the line $p:x-1=0$ is fixed symbolically $f(p)=p$

ii) the line $q:y=0$ gets mapped into the line $q':y+2=0$

iii) the line $r:y+2=0$ gets mapped into the line $r':x-y-4=0$

My aim is to find cartesian coordinate for the application so I started writing parametric forms of the lines and trying to calculate the parameters that defines $f$ explicitly but this lead me to a bunch of wrong calculations and contradictory results so I really don't know how to proceed in any other direction or where I've mistaken in my own.

Comment: Could you confirm that line i) is fixed point by point and that lines ii) and iii) are globally invariant (but not point by point). Is it that ? It looks like there is no solution

Comment: @JeanMarie yes I've copied the exercise as it is

Comment: Does condition (i) mean that every point on $p$ gets mapped to itself or only that a point on $p$ gets mapped to *some* point on $p$, not necessarily itself? There still might not be any such map, but the second condition isn’t a constraining as the first. I’m inclined to think that it’s the latter given that the other two conditions map lines to lines without specifying how individual points on those lines are affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such an affine transform

$$\begin{pmatrix}x'\\y'\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a & c\\b & d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}e \\f\end{pmatrix}$$

doesn't exist.

One should have, for the first two constraints (we do not need the third constraint iii)):

- constraint i): point by point invariance of points $(1,u)$:

$$\tag{1}\forall u \in \mathbb{R} \ \ \  \begin{pmatrix}1\\u\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a & c\\b & d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ u\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}e \\f\end{pmatrix}$$

- constraint ii): global invariance : a point with ordinate $0$ is transformed into a point with ordinate $-2$:

$$\tag{2}\forall v \in \mathbb{R} \ \ \begin{pmatrix}*\\-2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a & c\\b & d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}v \\ 0\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}e \\f\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\tag{3}(1) \ \iff \ \forall u\begin{cases}1=a+cu+e\\u=b+du+f\end{cases} \ \iff \ \begin{cases}1=a+e \ \text{and} \ c=0\\1=b+f \ \text{and} \ d=1\end{cases}$$

$$\tag{4}(2) \ \iff \ \forall v, \ \ -2=bv+f  \ \iff \ b=0 \ \text{and} \ f=-2$$

BUT, if the last 2 equations are added, we have $b+f=-2$, in contradiction with $b+f=1$ found in (3).

Comment: Thanks, that explains why all my calculations where contradictory, my teacher probably mispelled some signs.